# Can't change local account to microsoft account (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, microsoft-account

I have the following problem:

- I made an upgrade from Win 7 to Win 10
- All my files and settings were overtaken
- I have a local admin-account
- When I enter my microsoft-account in cortana the login-prompt dissapears without an error
- When I enter my microsoft-account in the store it tells me to try it later
- When I enter my microsoft-account under accounts (Login with microsoft-account instead) the login-prompt also dissapears
- When I add a new account with my ms-credentials it works fine.

Problem is that I don't want to change my account, because I want to keep my settings and files where they are.

Help is appreciated.